# Android findViewById in JUnit tests to access contents of a DialogFragment

Tags: android, findviewbyid, dialogfragment

I am writing test cases to check the contents of DialogFragment, which has a sepparate layout with multiple textviews. I want to assert, if certain textviews in DialogFragment instance are visible, but i can't find a proper way to use findViewById(), because i am getting NullPoinerExceptions, when using parent activity as a context. I also tried to use LayoutInflater to create rootview with the layout source of that dialog and use that view as a context. But i am starting to think, that by doing this i am not getting the actual content of displayed dialog, but instead i am creating a new instance of view and its childrens. So when i use findViewById() with the newly created view as a context, i am not getting access to the dialog, that was created in test case.

So my question is, what is the proper way to access layout elements of DialogFragment with findViewById() function